# What is Hermione Granger's favorite color?

Tags: harry-potter, hermione-granger

I can't find anywhere in the books or on the internet where it says Hermione's favorite color or colors. So, if you know, please answer. It would be best if you have evidence from J. K. Rowling or the books to back up your answer.

Comment: Interesting and valid question.

Comment: [Blue - no, yelloooooooooow!](https://youtu.be/pWS8Mg-JWSg?t=81)

Comment: I don't know about Hermione, but according to Alexa (Amazon UK), Emma Watson's [favorite color](https://alexaanswers.amazon.co.uk/question/2yXrcestenlqMjHRTuhROG) is light blue.

Comment: I've seen some vague comments that reference Pottermore mentioning Hermione Granger favorite color was violet. However, I can't find any solid proof.

Comment: I'd have thought it was ginger.